# where do I put this code so that it appears in the alert

Tags: jquery

```
$('td.qid').text().
```

The code above will determine which row the alert is refering to. Below is what the alert looks like:

```
You have not entered a valid Question 

Please Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question 

Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question
```

I want the alert to look like below:

```
You have errors on question number: 1 

You have not entered a valid Question 

Please Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question 

Please enter in a figure for Number of Marks for this Question
```

My question is that where do I put "You have errors on question number" and the code     `$('td.qid').text()`  in the function below to be able to display the 'You have errors on question number: 1' on the top of the alert?

Below is the validation function:

```
var qnum = 1; 

function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody');  
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>"); 
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>"); 

$tr.append($qid); 
$tbody.append($tr);  

   $(form).find('.numberOfQuestions').val(qnum); 

    ++qnum; 
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum); 

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say your html page looks like this:

```
> <html> <body> 
> <table border="1" width="200">
>     <tr>
>         <td class='qid'>1</td> 
>         <td>bla bla</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         <td class='qid'>2</td>
>         <td>bla bla</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         <td class='qid'>3</td>
>         <td>bla bla</td>
>     </tr> 
> </table> 
> </body> </html>
```

Then you add a jQuery code like this:

```
$("tr").click(function(e){
    var _qid = $("td.qid", this).text();
    var _msg = "You have errors on question number:" + _qid ;
    alert(_msg );
});
```

By doing this you add a click event on every  then pick the text of the column with the class qid and build your message.

you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/franky/f956k/